# What is USB Handle?

Tags: usb, usb-host

I came across this word while reading on how to configure MPSSE ports in FT2232H. It is said that "FT_GetDeviceInfoList" call returns "Device ID, USB location ID, USB Serial Number and USB Handle". Kindly let me know fast as I'm reaching the deadline for my project.

Comment: Needs more context. There are several meanings.

Comment: If you're reaching a deadline using FTDI D2XX and this is your question, your prior research is unacceptably lacking. FTDI has one full D2XX manual and at least one example for each language, not to mention complete functional code in the D2XX manuals.

Comment: This site doesn't care how urgent it is for people. We care for quality questions and quality answers that create a database of Q&A that can later help people that search through it.

Comment: Being genuine, I quoted the need and status of my project. If it seems to be disturbing to someone, I'm sorry. Kindly forgive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "handle" is a generic identifier for an arbitrary device or piece of information. In the case of USB, a "USB handle" is an identifier for a USB device. It is passed to further USB API functions in order to interact with the USB device.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please specify the difference between Device ID, USB location ID, USB Serial Number and USB Handle.

Comment: http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/

Comment: What is USB location ID? I couldn't find it there.

Comment: @Emil: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?usinglocationids.htm